# python intercept logging to email or sms

Tags: python, logging

I'm wondering whether it's possible to intercept a logging call to send an email or sms based on the level.

Bearing in mind that under email and sms, there is also `logging.error` which could cause a loop

```
import logging, smtplib, urllib2

LOGGER = 'log.out'
FORMAT = '%(asctime)s %(levelname)s %(message)s'
LEVEL = logging.INFO

logging.basicConfig(filename=LOGGER, format=FORMAT, maxBytes=2048, level=LEVEL)

def email(_msg):
    try:
        email_mesg = "Subject:{0}\n\n{1}".format(email_subj, _msg)
        s = smtplib.SMTP(email_host)
        s.sendmail(email_from, email_recv, email_mesg)
        s.quit()
    except smtplib.SMTPException as e:
        logging.error(e)

def sms(_msg):
    try:
        sms_mesg = urllib2.quote(_msg)
        url = "https://smsapi/?username={0}&password={1}&message={2}&orig={3}&number={4}".format(sms_user, sms_pass, sms_mesg, sms_orig, sms_numb)
        req = urllib2.Request(url)
        res = urllib2.urlopen(req)
    except urllib2.URLError as e:
        logging.error(e)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    """
    The following line should log and trigger email
    """
    logging.warning("Something you should know about")

    """
    The following line should log and trigger sms
    """
    logging.error("Something you should know about")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a [Filter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#filter-objects):

```
import sys, logging

class SMSEmailFilter(logging.Filter):
    def filter(self, record):
        if not record.args:
            if record.levelno == logging.WARN:
                email(record.msg)
            elif record.levelno >= logging.ERROR:
                sms(record.msg)
        return True

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG, format='%(asctime)s %(levelname)s %(message)s', stream=sys.stdout)
logger = logging.getLogger()
logger.addFilter(SMSEmailFilter())


def email(_msg):
    try:
        print "Sending email..."
    except:
        logger.error('from email', {'a': 1})


def sms(_msg):
    try:
        print "Sending sms..."
    except:
        logger.error('from sms', {'a': 1})


logger.warning('This is a warning')
logger.error('This is an error')
```

Comment: Awesome. Thank you for the introduction to addFilter. Would this not cause an infinite loop in sms if it errored though?

Comment: record.level isnt correct, it would be `levelno` or `levelname` https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html#logging.LogRecord

Comment: I hope you dont mind if i edit your answer to be the complete solution just so Im not adding an extra answer, after all, it was your solution

Comment: I tried but it says "This edit will be visible only to you until it is peer reviewed."